# How to map a parent attribute to a child object when deserializing JSON into Java objects?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Given JSON like this:

```
{
    "locale" : "US",
    "children" : [
            {
                "foo" : "bar"
            },
            {
                "foo" : "baz"
            }
        ]
}
```

being mapped to Java objects like this:

```
public class Parent {
    @JsonProperty public String getLocale() {...}
    @JsonProperty public List<Child> getChildren() {...}
}

public class Child {
    public void setLocale(String locale) {...}
    @JsonProperty public String getFoo() {...}
}
```

How can I populate the locale property of Child instances with the value that is in the JSON at the top (`Parent`) level?

I thought I might be able to use `@JsonDeserialize(using=MyDeserializer.class)` on the `setLocale()` method of `Child` to use a custom serializer, but that's not working (I suspect because there is no value in the JSON at the Child level so Jackson doesn't know about any values that are supposed to be deserialized into the `locale` property).

I'd like to avoid having to write an entire custom deserializer for the entire `Child` class, which in reality has lots more data to be mapped.

Answer (score 3):

If it is acceptable to have a reference to a parent in a child object, then you can use [bi-directional references](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences) to establish the parent-child relationship between you classes. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonParentChild {
    public static class Parent {
        public String locale;
        @JsonManagedReference
        public List<Child> children;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Parent{" +
                    "locale='" + locale + '\'' +
                    ", children=" + children +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static class Child {
        @JsonBackReference
        public Parent parent;
        public String foo;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Child{" +
                    "locale='" + parent.locale + '\'' +
                    ", foo='" + foo + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    final static String json = "{\n" +
            "    \"locale\" : \"US\",\n" +
            "    \"children\" : [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"foo\" : \"bar\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"foo\" : \"baz\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Parent parent = mapper.readValue(json, Parent.class);
        System.out.println("Dumping the object");
        System.out.println(parent);
        System.out.println("Serializing to JSON");
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(parent));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Dumping the object:
Parent{locale='US', children=[Child{locale='US', foo='bar'}, Child{locale='US', foo='baz'}]}
Serializing to JSON:
{
  "locale" : "US",
  "children" : [ {
    "foo" : "bar"
  }, {
    "foo" : "baz"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I do control the object model so there's nothing strictly stopping me from doing this. However it isn't a natural way for the object model to be structured so I'll have to think about whether or not it's worth that trade-off.